# Route uses Slug, but id needed for function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, route-model-binding

I'm using slugs to navigate in my site, but I need the id connected to the slug for a function.

Function:

```
public function categories(Request $request, $slug)
{
    $categories = Category::where('slug', $slug)->get();
    $announcements = Announcement::where('category_id', $request->id)->paginate(5);
    $category_lists = Category::all();
    return view('announcements.index', compact('announcements', 'categories', 'category_lists'));
}
```

This is the function where I need to get the ID. $request->id isn't working since my $request->id returns 'null'. Is there any way to get the id that's connected to the slug/DB row?

If any more information is needed please tell me.

I've tried getting it with

```
$announcements = Announcement::where('category_id', Category::get(id))->paginate(5);
```

and things alike, nothing worked.

Comment: Do you have multiple categories with the same `slug`?

Comment: Nope, every category has a unique slug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you override the `getRouteKeyName` in your `Category` model:

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'slug';
}
```

Then you can get the `Category` like this with the route model binding:

```
public function categories(Request $request, Category $category)
{
    $announcements = Announcement::where('category_id', $category->id)->paginate(5);
    $category_lists = Category::all();
    return view('announcements.index', compact('announcements', 'category', 'category_lists'));
}
```

Comment: This doesn't show the posts connected to said categories.

Comment: if you try in your controller method `dd($category)` do you get the category that you are looking for?

Comment: so your Category is empty as it looks from the image. Did you added the `getRouteKeyName` in your `Category` model?

Comment: and please show me how did you define your route? do you use `{category}`, or `{slug}`?

Comment: I changed it to {category} and now it does work, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to

```
$category = Category::where('slug', $slug)->first();
$announcements = Announcement::where('category_id', $category->id)->paginate(5);
```

if one category has one unique slug, just use `first()`, instead of `get()` and you can get the category object and use it.

Comment: @SpookyCode Nakov's solution is better, you should use Route-Model binding concept.